# how can I do this select query

Tags: sql

I have in my SQL Server, a table called FavoriteUsers with a list of users and a table called Users with all users.

In my `ASPX` page, I have a `TextBox` where my user can put the ID of an User to list in my `GridView`.

**How it works**

By default, I fill my GridView with all data of my FavoriteUsers table, and if the user of my system put some user code in the `textbox` field and click on my button to find these users, I'll reload the GridView with the FavoriteUsers and the users that he put on `TextBox` field that come from the table `Users`.

How can I do this `SELECT` query ?

Comment: If you tell us how are your tables related we can help you with the query, otherwise its guessing work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from FavoriteUsers
UNION
select * from Users 
Where userid = 'TextBox.text'
```

Of course you can't use TextBox.text in there. But you only needed the query so you get the point.

**NOTE**: The UNION will leave out any records from Users that already exist in FavoriteUsers. So you won't have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Get all favorite users plus the user whose username matches that entered into the textbox:

```
SELECT Users.*
FROM Users
  LEFT JOIN FavoriteUsers ON Users.UserID = FavoriteUsers.UserID
WHERE (FavoriteUsers.UserID IS NOT NULL) OR (Users.Username = @Username)
```

Comment: This is not what he asked for. It's actually the other way around. He wants all FavoriteUsers and only the records from Users that have the userId provided in the textbox. Sidenote: Imo he shoundl't include validation (the Not Null part) in the query. He should do that client side with javascript if he wants to.

Comment: I guess I made an incorrect assumption about his DB design.  I figured he would have all user data in the Users table.  The FavoriteUsers table would contain a FK to the Users table, plus some additional info, such as why they are a favorite user.  In that case, the query I specified would work just fine.  Having the same user data in two separate tables is not a good design.

Comment: Agreed. The Schema you describe would indeed be better and your query would work if that was the case. I was just pointing out that it won't work for this case.